# Visual Studio 2013 GitHub avatar not being displayed

Tags: github, visual-studio-2013, avatar

I have set up my VS 2013 with GitHub and my problem is: when I commit to GitHub, I am not seeing my GitHub avatar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in this **[post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/02/26/customize-git-settings-in-visual-studio.aspx)**, you'll have to tweak the Visual Studio **Git settings** and tick the **"Enable download of author images from 3rd party source"** checkbox.

> If your Git repo remote origin is in a third-party Git service (such GitHub, Bitbucket, or CodePlex), select Enable download of author images from 3rd party source, and then ask team members to set up Gravatar accounts for their email addresses.

Applying this setting should allow you to see your GitHub avatar when working on your project from within Visual Studio.

[image]

Comment: @Stevo5o Did you connect your email address to a Gravatar account?

Comment: Gravatar account, I have been looking at this. 
Do I really need a Gravatar account?

Comment: For this to work from within Visual Studio, you'll indeed need a Gravatar account. Check the blog post (or the excerpt of it in the answer above).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I have given up on GitHub in VS 2013, it's way too much hard work. I have gone back to GitHub in the cli https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/

Git cli is much more straight forward and a lot easier to use, of course once you get used to the cli. Here is my gist of Git cli commands that I use. https://gist.github.com/Stevo5o/90764aa1f5f4f81b07d4

Answer (score 0):

Where you don't see your avatar, inside Visual Studio interface or on GitHub?

If later, I think you haven't entered correct e-mail in settings of git integration for Visual Studio.

Or you can manually create `.gitconfig` file in your home folder with following contents:

```
[user]
    name = Your Name
    email = your.name@email.com
```

However this will not change information for already created commits. But for all upcoming commits `git` will use correct e-mail and GitHub will be able match it with your account and use avatar you've uploaded earlier.

Needless to say, that in configuration file you should use only e-mail known by GitHub, otherwise it would not be able to match your commit to your account.

Regarding your avatar inside Visual Studio, I'm not sure is it supported by `git` integration.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but no it is in visual studio.