# How to prevent Team Foundation Server Webinterface from showing Gravatar Images?

Tags: tfs, gravatar

I have a private Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server (Version 15.117) running in my network.

When I look at the history of a Git project (like `https://tfs.local/tfs/»Collection«/»Project«/_git/»Repository«/history?_a=history`) in the author column there are avatars shown.
TFS automatically(?) retrieves authors Gravatar image through URL `https://tfs.local/tfs/»Collection«/»Project«/_api/_common/IdentityImage?id=&email=»none%4example.net«%3E&defaultGravatar=mm&__v=5` that *302 Found* redirects to `https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/»md5-hash«`

With this behaviour, Gravatar (and possible entities in between) know my project and repository names, which is not acceptable.

How can I prevent the webinterface to display Gravatar (and other 3rd party) images? Locally upladed images are okay.

([Visual Studio 2013 GitHub avatar not being displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29696154/) is not related as this is a setting for Visual Studio and "Enable 3rd party source" already is un-ticked)

Comment: How/Where did you commit your changes? Are you able to see the Gravatar image in your profile in TFS?

Comment: In this case I cloned an OpenSource repository and pushed that to my private TFS server - and then Gravatar images appeared next to the commits of 3rd party peoples.
Luckily I can't see Gravatar image in my profile, I set a separate profile picture there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such setting in TFS to prevent TFS from showing images. I've submitted a uservoice at website below, you could vote it:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/32964319-prevent-team-foundation-server-webinterface-from-s